# How to decide if a torque is positive or negative?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque, moment-of-inertia

[image]

In part i, I use $T=I\frac{d^2Q}{dt^2}$ , and get $T=\frac{23g}{150a}\sin Q$ , but the answer is $T=\frac{-23g}{150a}\sin Q$.

The only way I can get this answer is if I use $T=-I\frac{d^2Q}{dt^2}$ , but isn't this incorrect, as the torque is increasing the angular velocity, not decreasing it, so $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dQ}{dt}\right)>0$ , and thus the torque too should be greater than $0$.

Comment: Use the right-hand rule.

Answer (score 1):

Once you make a choice of how your spatial axes are oriented according to your diagram you are no longer free to "pick a sign" for the quantity $\vec{r} \times \vec{f}$. If you diagram is 2D, you can still choose where the positive direction is along the remaining 3D orthogonal direction

In defining angular quantities like torque or angular momentum, you have also the choice of placing the origin of coordinates where you want, but typically expressions become much simpler when the origin of coordinates coincides with a point of symmetry in the problem

Answer (score 0):

You must be consistent to what you define as positive. Given the picture above, the sum of moments about the pivot point is (considering the positive direction the clockwise direction):

$$ 
\circlearrowright \sum M=I_o\alpha\\
23mga\sin \theta=150ma^2\alpha
$$

But $\theta$ is defined positive counter-clockwise, so $\alpha=-\ddot{\theta}$.

Therefore,

$$
23mga\sin \theta=-150ma^2\ddot{\theta}
$$

The resultant is:

$$
\ddot{\theta} = -\frac{23g}{150a}\sin \theta
$$

If you define the positive direction the ccw direction, then the LHS of the equation is negative, but $\alpha=\ddot{\theta}$. The final result, however, does not change.

Comment: Please do not post complete solutions to homework-like problems.  Doing so is contrary to the spirit and "rules" of the forum.  I suggest you edit the answer to address only the issue of the torques.

Comment: @Thales What angle is alpha? Why is it the 'default' angle we get when we use C= I alpha?

Comment: written in general terms, $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration about a fixed pivot

Answer (score 0):

The restoring force is in the opposite direction to the angle $\theta$. The restoring force is toward the downward vertical (the equilibrium position), whereas angle $\theta$ is measured away from the downward vertical.

Answer (score 0):

For a 2D problem such as this, use the same convention for torque as angles. If a positive angle is counter-clockwise then a positive torque should be counter-clockwise also.

The issue in this situation is that the sketch does not show which direction is the positive angle $\theta$. Does a positive angle tips the circle up or down? So when they say $\dot{\theta} = \tfrac{3}{5} \sqrt{ \frac{g}{a} } $ you have no idea which way this thing is spinning.

> So the correct answer depends on the convention the author has chosen, which is not stated clearly.